# Register Target with ASG via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using Terraform to provision an application load balancer (ALB) and an autoscaling group (ASG).  I have a target group set up, and the ALB forwards requests to that target group.  However, my instances launching in my ASG are not automatically registered with the target group.  I added the following line to my configuration:

```
target_group_arns         = [aws_lb_target_group.example-tg.arn]
```

However, after I execute 'terraform apply', I look at the infrastructure that has been provisioned, and I still need to manually register my instance with the target group.

When I execute 'terraform apply', I get the following error:

```
Error: "foobar3-terraform-test": Waiting up to 10m0s: Need at least 1 healthy instances in ASG, have 0. Most recent activity: {
  ActivityId: "e8e5c84d-93ff-6047-147e-b7f935edd18a",
  AutoScalingGroupName: "foobar3-terraform-test",
  Cause: "At 2020-05-14T13:34:14Z a user request update of AutoScalingGroup constraints to min: 1, max: 4, desired: 1 changing the desired capacity from 0 to 1.  At 2020-05-14T13:34:43Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.",
  Description: "Launching a new EC2 instance: i-05ccb2f6f952bef7c",
  Details: "{\"Subnet ID\":\"subnet-0e1090a9a5ced6513\",\"Availability Zone\":\"us-east-1a\"}",
  Progress: 40,
  StartTime: 2020-05-14 13:34:45.72 +0000 UTC,
  StatusCode: "MidLifecycleAction"
}
```

Below is my full configuration for reference:

```
  1 provider "aws" {
  2   region = "us-east-1"
  3 }
  4
  5 resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  6   cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  7 }
  8
  9 resource "aws_security_group" "http" {
 10   name        = "http"
 11   description = "Allow HTTP inbound traffic"
 12   vpc_id      = aws_vpc.example.id
 13
 14   ingress {
 15     description = "TLS from anywhere"
 16     from_port   = 80
 17     to_port     = 80
 18     protocol    = "tcp"
 19     cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 20   }
 21
 22   egress {
 23     from_port   = 0
 24     to_port     = 0
 25     protocol    = "-1"
 26     cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 27   }
 28 }
 29
 30 resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
 31   vpc_id = aws_vpc.example.id
 32 }
 33
 34 resource "aws_default_route_table" "route_to_internet" {
 35   default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.example.default_route_table_id
 36   route {
 37     cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
 38     gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
 39   }
 40 }
 41
 42 resource "aws_subnet" "example_subnet_1" {
 43   vpc_id               = aws_vpc.example.id
 44   cidr_block           = "10.0.1.0/24"
 45   availability_zone_id = "use1-az1"
 46 }
 47
 48 resource "aws_subnet" "example_subnet_2" {
 49   vpc_id               = aws_vpc.example.id
 50   cidr_block           = "10.0.2.0/24"
 51   availability_zone_id = "use1-az2"
 52 }
 53
 54 resource "aws_lb" "example-alb" {
 55   name               = "example-alb"
 56   internal           = false
 57   load_balancer_type = "application"
 58   security_groups    = [aws_security_group.http.id]
 59   subnets            = [aws_subnet.example_subnet_1.id, aws_subnet.example_subnet_2.id]
 60
 61   enable_deletion_protection = false
 62 }
 63
 64 resource "aws_lb_target_group" "example-tg" {
 65   name     = "example-tg"
 66   port     = 80
 67   protocol = "HTTP"
 68   vpc_id   = aws_vpc.example.id
 69 }
 70
 71 resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb-listener" {
 72   load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.example-alb.id
 73   port              = "80"
 74   protocol          = "HTTP"
 75
 76   default_action {
 77     type             = "forward"
 78     target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.example-tg.arn
 79   }
 80 }
 81
 82 resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment" {
 83   autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.bar.name
 84   alb_target_group_arn   = aws_lb_target_group.example-tg.arn
 85 }
 86
 87 resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example-lc" {
 88   name                        = "terraform-lc"
 89   image_id                    = "ami-0323c3dd2da7fb37d"
 90   instance_type               = "t2.micro"
 91   associate_public_ip_address = true
 92   user_data                   = "#!/usr/bin/env bash\nsudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1.12\nsudo yum -y install nginx\nsudo systemctl start nginx"
 93   security_groups             = [aws_security_group.http.id]
 94   key_name                    = "tf_example"
 95 }
 96
 97 resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
 98   name                      = "foobar3-terraform-test"
 99   max_size                  = 4
100   min_size                  = 1
101   health_check_grace_period = 300
102   desired_capacity          = 1
103   force_delete              = true
104   launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.example-lc.name
105   target_group_arns         = [aws_lb_target_group.example-tg.arn]
106   vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.example_subnet_1.id, aws_subnet.ex    ample_subnet_2.id]
107
108   initial_lifecycle_hook {
109     name                 = "foobar"
110     default_result       = "CONTINUE"
111     heartbeat_timeout    = 2000
112     lifecycle_transition = "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING"
113   }
114
115   tag {
116     key                 = "name"
117     value               = "example-instance"
118     propagate_at_launch = true
119   }
120 }
```

Comment: Has your instance needs to send a heartbeat, look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/complete-lifecycle-action.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the below health_check_type in your autoscaling resource block. You have to mention if your using the EC2 health check or the ELB health check. Since your load balancer does not have the health check configuration. It should be EC2. (the health check is based on the status checks of the instance)

`health_check_type = "EC2"`

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html

Comment: This is the default behaviour so doesn't need specifying. You've almost stumbled onto a good answer though by suggesting that they use ELB healthchecks for the ASG which would also allow them to drop the lifecycle hook because the ELB won't put the instance into service until NGINX is running and serving traffic which seems to be what the OP is trying to do with their lifecycle hook (but is missing the bit that actually completes the lifecycle hook).